# Why would the TEMP environment variable contain more than one path?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

A colleague's `%TEMP%` environment variable has this value:

```
C:\Users\his.name\AppData\Local\Temp; C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v78\runtime\win32; C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v713\runtime\win32
```

Note how it contains *three* semicolon-separated paths, whereas one would normally expect it to contain just one path (by default, the first of those three). We have no idea how this happened. Maybe the Matlab installer... we don't know.

Now, this is causing me trouble because an internal application that I wrote and that the whole company is using tries to get the path of the temp folder, but gets confused because the value of `TEMP` isn't a valid path (because as we can see it's actually three paths).

The question is thus:

- Is there a reason to have the TEMP environment variable contain more than one path?
- Is this supported behavior or is this a bug?
- Is it safe for my colleague to just remove those two weird Matlab paths from `TEMP` and keep only the first one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does seem as if Matlab accidentally appended to `TEMP` instead of `PATH`.  Given that there are plenty of programs which assume `TEMP` is a single directory rather than a list, I would recommend removing the extra directories.

If these directories exist and contain Matlab executables, you might want to add them to the `PATH`.

Comment: A similar error was reported here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736607/a-bad-tmp-path-variable-causes-team-explorer-to-return-404-not-found-connection-errors-when-connecting-to-a-tfs-server   It is definitely an error to have tmp/temp paths with multiple directories.